# Resolve linker errors in GNU for redeclaration

Tags: c++, linux, gnu

I have the following implementation:

header of A:

```
class A
{
public:
foo();
};
```

A has its own .cpp file with the implementation for foo()

//header of B

```
#include "A.h"
class B
{
public foo();
};
```

Note: B does not have a header of its own

Now in the Class C.cpp,  I want to reuse header of A and implementation from B.o. So in C.cpp I do:

```
//C.cpp
#include "A.h"
....
B b;
b.foo();
..
```

When I compile the above I am bound to get redeclaration error for the function foo(). I want to know if there is any way to tell GNU compiler to take B.o and omit A.o... Or to tell compiler to consider the first object in the make file that contains the implementation and ignore the rest?

I am using GNU v2.16

Comment: A better solution would be to move `foo` into a free function and then call it inside the member functions.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is about redeclaration of `A` since in `C.cpp` it will see 2 declarations of `A` one through `A.h` and other through `B.h`, so just guard `A.h` in a header guard to avoid including it more than once, generally you should always guard your headers:

```
#ifndef HEADER_A_h_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_A_h_INCLUDED
class A {...};
#endif
```

Now if you include `A.h` more than one time this guard will make the second include as nothing!

Comment: thanks for the answer...but I have added that for A.h. And my B.cpp reuses the header of A. so in essence I do not have a seperate header for B.  so I would get a redifinition error unless I can tell the compiler to omit the defination and in A.cpp and pick it from B.cpp

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, you have one implementation of `A::foo` in `A.cpp` and one in `B.cpp`?